# PHP: Should a checking function throw an exception

Tags: php, exception, error-checking

This doesn't necessarily only apply to PHP, but that's my area of concern.

I have been writing a few checking functions recently, that get some argument and then check its validity in various ways. Like, checkXmlString($xml) will check whether the given string contains a well-formed xml document, etc.

The question is, should those functions return a boolean, or throw exceptions and not return anything on success.

So

```
function checkAbc($arg) { if ($arg is invalid) return false; else return true; }
```

or rather

```
function checkAbc($arg) { if ($arg is invalid) throw new Exception(...); }
```

Comment: I would rename to isXmlString and return boolean..., since its a function to check seems strange to throw an Exception, this you throw if you have problems checking it.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw a [InvalidArgumentException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) to check if arguments are incorrect but i think for your case if you are writing "checkers" they should return a boolean so you know not to continue operations, for example if the foobar.xml is actually a CSV file you wouldn't want to continue with your operation but you wouldn't want to catch an exeption either

```
<?php 
class Checker {
    function validXml($string)
    {
        if(!(bool)$string) throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Cannot pass empty string as argument", 1);
        // Check
        // Is valid XML ? Return True : return false
    }
}
try {
    if(new Checker->validXml($xmlString))
    {
        // Continue Operation
        // return 
    }
    // Notify User of invalidity
    // return
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // Log args 
    // 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is generally 2 types of function regarding your question:

- Pure function that tests whether a condition holds.
- Function that ensures a condition holds and alters control flow if it does not.

Different programming language may have different conventions  about the naming of both types. Take `C++` as an example, one common naming is `CHECK_XXX` for type 2 and `IsXXX` for type 1.
Here is an example taken from a [tutorial](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html) of the google-log library:

```
CHECK(fp->Write(x) == 4) << "Write failed!";
CHECK_NE(1, 2) << ": The world must be ending!";
```

Another example is the [maktaba](https://github.com/google/vim-maktaba) utility library for `Vimscript` , where `maktaba#value#IsXXX()` is used to test whether the argument is of a certain type while `maktaba#ensure#IsXXX()` is used to *ensure* `IsXXX` holds and throws an exception otherwise.

```
function! TakeAString(name)
  " Ensure argument type is String.
  let name = maktaba#ensure#IsString(a:name)
endfunction

if maktaba#value#IsString(name)
  " Branch if name is a String.
  echo name
endif
```

**So here is the point:** choose the one that suits your need best and name the function according to the convention of the language. In terms of use cases of both, roughly, use the type 2 to check pre-condition like argument type and use the type 1 in conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not quite sure which form is preferrable in general.

On the one hand, in case of an error, you want a useful message, so you end up with mixed returns (true/string), which is ugly, or returning an array (even uglier). An exception gives you that for free.

On the other hand, a function called check...() should not be expected to throw an exception, because finding out that "this is not a valid thingie" is nothing exceptional and not an error.

The third way would be to call it "throwIfFalse", but that's ugly too....

Hmm....

One possible solution:

```
interface Checker {
  public function check();
  public function getMessage();
}
class WhateverChecker implements Checker { ... }

class ClientOfChecker {
  public function doStuff() {
     $checker = new Checker();
     if (! $checker->check() )
        throw new Exception($checker->getMessage());
  }
}
```

However, that seems incredibly verbose, and, may I say, Javaesque to me.

Answer (score 0):

According to almost all books written on subject and not least, according to logic, the name should be the biggest hint of what the function does. In that case, only the first option applies. As Bet Lamed said previously, a function called "check" is not supposed to throw exceptions, just to let you know if the check is ok or not.

If you want exceptions, you might want to rename it to DeserialisationToAbc() or TryParseAbc() or something similar.

Comment: Sure, I mean the public interface, most probably, should be like

    parseXml() throws WhateverException

but then if those checks get a bit more extensive, you'd have a lot of code at the top of parseXml() which clutters it up and makes the function less readable, so you want to separate checking code from ... ahm.... "actually doing stuff" code, and then you're back to return values to signify the validity.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, should those functions return a boolean, or throw
>   exceptions and not return anything on success.

First identify If It is an exceptional situation than use exception .You case does not seems to be exceptional, It is just a condition , so treat it like a condition.If It was like It is correct but fails on certain situation, you may not identify well than you may consider using exception.

Visit these two links and learn more about exception

[Exception Best Practices in PHP 5.3](http://ralphschindler.com/2010/09/15/exception-best-practices-in-php-5-3)

[A primer on PHP exceptions](http://nitschinger.at/A-primer-on-PHP-exceptions)

Comment: ".You case does not seems to be exceptional, It is just a condition"

NOt to get too philosophical, but it's a bit of a weird combination. You'd most probably only ever use a check function on something you assume to be correct, so incorrectness is an exceptional circumstance; but the checker function doesn't really KNOW that, so it should return a boolean.

Comment: incorrectness is not exceptional, if you are clear when you will get boolean false. if you are uncertain about the condition when you are getting boolean false, It can be treated as exceptional situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course a bit opinion based, but ask yourself, what do *you* expect from a function like `checkEmail()` ? The purpose of the method is to validate something, so you propably expect an answer to this question.

```
$isValid = checkEmail($arg);
```

I think most developers expect a bool as return value, it makes the code readable. Wrong values are expected, so one cannot say it is an exception if an invalid argument is passed. To return an error message as well i would use an out parameter:

```
function checkAbc($arg, &$errorMessage)
{
  if ($arg is invalid)
  {
    $errorMessage = 'The argument is invalid because of...';
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    $errorMessage = '';
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah that might be a good solution. Interesting, I practically never use output parameters, so that one didn't even occur to me...

Comment: @BetLamed - This is to [avoid mixed-typed return values](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#mixedReturnType). I think mixing types is quite dangerous so i wrote the small article.